# Motion capture movement from 3d model animation

Tags: animation, bones

I have a set of animations of a model with a complex rig that I would like to copy to another model that is unrigged.The original model has more than 250 bones in total and it would take a really long time to convert the whole animation set.

I wonder if there is a way to motion capture the 3d animations and apply them on my model or another solution that wouldn't be so time consuming.

Comment: Try using a [deform mesh](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/mesh_deform.html) modifier, this is similar to a lattice in that a mesh contained within the deform mesh will deform with it.